# Draw a triangle with a grid inside

Tags: swing, graphics, geometry, awt, paint

I'm attempting to draw a triangle that has a grid inside. Much like graphing paper. I have the grid, and the triangle drawn, but I don't know how to remove the excess grid. The grid currently is drawn in a for loop until it gets to the end of the triangle's length. The problem is, this will draw a box 'grid' on top of the triangle. Can I draw on top of the excess to get rid of it? Should I draw the lines differently or draw multiple triangles inside the large one to simulate a grid? Assistance would be appreciated.

```
public class TrianglePanel extends JPanel{

final int pixelParameter = 20;
final int HEIGHT = 800, WIDTH = HEIGHT;

public TrianglePanel(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
    setBackground(Color.white);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    int [] xPoints = {0,WIDTH/2,0};
    int [] yPoints = {HEIGHT,HEIGHT,HEIGHT/2};

    g.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3); // Draws the triangle

    for (int i = pixelParameter; i < WIDTH/2; i += pixelParameter){
        g.drawLine(i, HEIGHT, i, (HEIGHT/2)); // Draws vertical lines
        g.drawLine(0, HEIGHT - i, (WIDTH/2), HEIGHT - i); // Draws horizontal lines
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method, not the paint() method.
2. Don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent() at the start so the background gets painted.
3. Create a `Polygon` object. Then you can try using the `Graphics.setClip(Shape)` method before you attempt to draw the grid lines.